# Can high network usage be detected and prevented in Tor?

Tags: encryption, linux, tor, anonymity, debian

I've already asked this question [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/can-high-network-usage-be-detected-and-prevented-in-tor) but as of yet it has no views/answers.

I was wondering if there is any way for Tor to detect high network usage in the context of transferring large files using a hidden service.

If so, what are the default prevention steps?

Comment: Are you trying to measure total traffic over Tor or only traffic for large file transfers over Tor?

Comment: I'm more interested in the possibility of detecting  high network usage and any prevention mechanisms.